# How to use If and Boolean to pass a TDD test

Tags: javascript, tdd

Here is the task:

> In English, the colors of the rainbow are often listed as:
>
> red orange yellow green blue indigo violet
>
> Declare a function called `isRainbowColor`. Use case-insensitive
> checking, i.e. `"red"`, `"Red"`, `"RED"`, `"ReD"`, and `"rEd"` are all valid
> rainbow colors.
>
> ```
> /**
>
> @param {string} ??? - the color to check @returns {boolean} whether or not the given color is a rainbow color */
> ```

Here is what I have so far (I know this is not enough!):

```
function isRainbowColor(string){
  let rainbowColor = [];
  for (const string of rainbowColor){
    if (string != rainbowColor){
      return true;
}else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the error message that I get:

[image: error message]

Here is the test that I could not pass with my code above:

```
actual = isRainbowColor("red");
expected = true;

if (actual === expected) {
  console.log("Test PASSED!");
} else {
  console.error("Test FAILED. Keep trying!");
  console.group("Result:");
  console.log("  actual:", actual);
  console.log("expected:", expected);
  console.groupEnd();
}

actual = isRainbowColor("rEd");
expected = true;

if (actual === expected) {
  console.log("Test PASSED!");
} else {
  console.error("Test FAILED. Keep trying!");
  console.group("Result:");
  console.log("  actual:", actual);
  console.log("expected:", expected);
  console.groupEnd();
}

actual = isRainbowColor("Brown");
expected = false;

if (actual === expected) {
  console.log("Test PASSED!");
} else {
  console.error("Test FAILED. Keep trying!");
  console.group("Result:");
  console.log("  actual:", actual);
  console.log("expected:", expected);
  console.groupEnd();
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting `for (const string of rainbowColor)` to do, given that you _just defined it_ to be an empty array?

Comment: I know, I am at a loss here with this task overall.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function isRainbowColor for your question :

So when using the function, you basically just have to just pass in a string as parameter (it doesn't matter if its uppercase, lowercase or mixed-case) and if it finds that string in the array "rainbowColors" then it will return true and if it doesn't finds that string in rainbowColors array, then it will return false

```js
function isRainbowColor(color) {
    var rainbowColors = ['violet', 'indigo', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'];
    color = color.toString().toLowerCase();

    rainbowColors.forEach(rainbowColor => {
        if (color == rainbowColor) {
            console.log(color + ' is a rainbow color');
            return true;
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

**Usage**

```js
-----------------------------------------------------------------

isRainbowColor('red');
Console : red is a rainbow color
true

-----------------------------------------------------------------

isRainbowColor('hi');
false

-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

> Edit : Added support for all lowercase, uppercase and mixed-case string as the parameter value. Ex :

```js
-----------------------------------------------------------------

isRainbowColor('RED');
red is a rainbow color
true

-----------------------------------------------------------------

isRainbowColor('RedddD');
false

-----------------------------------------------------------------

isRainbowColor('YeLlOW');
yellow is a rainbow color
true

-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: They _do_ define that function, it's in the first code block in their question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Oh yeah, sorry but this code is working fine

Comment: And which variable is being used before being declared?

Comment: @jonrsharpe. When I was typing the answer, the variable "actual" was not defined and then you edited the question and you defined it and I didn't see that and posted the answer.

You can also see in error message image, the error shows :

Result:
    actual: undefined
    expected: true

Comment: I just fixed the formatting, I didn't add any code (although maybe it made some visible that wasn't).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yea maybe. but the code I have written is working just fine

Comment: @BinaryBytes 

Thank you for helping, much appreciated!

Unfortunately (unless I misunderstood you), the code allows non-rainbow colors (i.e. grey or brown) to pass the test.

I edited my question with that code.

Comment: @SerkanToto, no, I have tested the code and it only allows colours that are in the array "rainbowColors"